# Query String is missing when calling exec() in PHP

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to create a pdf with a get parameter in the link.

My exec looks like this:

```
exec('/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf "' . 'http://www.mysite.be/this/that/other/print?debug=true' . '" ' . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pdffile/' . $strPdfName);
```

If I go to the URL manually, it's fine. But whenever I want to execute it, seems as if the parameter is cut off. There are no errors. Does anybody have any idea?

I've been searching for hours. It is getting the better of me..

Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: What would you do if `$strPdfName` was `; rm -rf --no-preserve-root /`?

Comment: he would probably cry

Comment: "BOOM, BABY!" bad programmers write code for the optimal case, good programmers write code for the limit cases, really good programmers write code for the evil cases.

Comment: I'm the one creating the string. No evil doers can touch it (I think..). Still, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Yes, I checked how I could sanitize the url and the name, and found some useful functions in PHP. Thanks for pointing it out, I should be more careful with these things. It's a bad habit.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably escape the parameter you are passing to exec using [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)

```
$url = escapeshellarg('http://www.kriski.be/skireizen/stages/technische-stage/print?debug=true');
$file = escapeshellarg($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pdfs/' . $strPdfName);

exec("/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf $url $file");
```

Comment: I tried, and it still is missing. Do you have any idea in which scenario's the exec would cut if off?

Comment: so the `/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf` script receives `http://www.kriski.be/skireizen/stages/technische-stage/print` without the `?debug=true` part? Or the pdf is missing debug information?

Answer (score 0):

I found it.. It wasn't that the query parameter wasn't getting through.. but that the pdf wasn't created. Because there were already pdf's with that name on the server, the old template was downloaded..

The culprit was in the CSS:

```
   @font-face {
     font-family: "Calibri Webfont";
     src: url("http://www.mywebsite.be/temps/def/css/fonts/calibri-webfont.ttf");
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
    }
```

Not yet sure why that would hold the PDF creation back or why I didn't get an error, but that's another thing.